# Plugin for Magento 2 site using TaxJar API in a drop ship model to address sales tax

Tags: magento2, tax, 3rd-party-library

Is there a plugin that will work with the **TaxJar API** to support a drop ship model where we can  set  our site to collect tax or not based on if a manufacture requires us to collect sales tax?  We are building the site on Magento 2.

For example, if manufacture A is going to charge us sales tax in VA but no other vendor is, would we be able to set up a plugin using **TaxJar API** to only collect in VA for manufacture A and no other manufactures? Is there a plugin that would allow us to code for that?

At my previous company we had built fulfiller manager. This had each vendor listed and then the ability to determine by state for each vendor if tax should be collected or not. That system then communicated with our tax software through API to determine if it should or should not be a taxable transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Their extension may have this feature. If it doesn't you could create an issue/feature request.

https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento2-extension

Answer (score -1):

Third-party extensions for drop-shipping or marketplaces may support Magento's built-in zip-based tax rate tables out of the box, but it's unlikely they'll support sales tax solutions like TaxJar.

The best way to approach this would be to customize the TaxJar M2 extension and look at custom attributes / data assigned to a given manufacturer. Ideally, you'd be able to store an array of nexus addresses for each manufacturer and pass it to [TaxJar's calculation endpoint](https://developers.taxjar.com/api/reference/#post-calculate-sales-tax-for-an-order). At a minimum you'll need a country, state, and zip code for each nexus location. We need zip codes to calculate tax in [origin-based states](https://blog.taxjar.com/charging-sales-tax-rates/) since it's based on the shipping origin.

If you decide to customize the extension, you can supply the specific nexus addresses [in this method](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento2-extension/blob/develop/Model/Smartcalcs.php#L385). You may need to supply the manufacturer data as an argument when [calling `_getNexusAddresses()` here](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento2-extension/blob/develop/Model/Smartcalcs.php#L166).

Comment: Thanks Jake.  Do you know anyone that has already developed this or could develop this for us?  It's got to be a fairly common need in e-commerce.  Thx

Comment: @michael You can find a Magento professional on [Commerce Hero](https://commercehero.io/) that should be able to help you out. Feel free to reach out to our support team with any questions along the way and I'll get them answered.